# Azure Active Directory and localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an issues with AAD on localhost.
I have well followed this [how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication)

The first step was to declare my app in registration and it is working on my azurewebsite.net.
Second step was to declare my https://localhost:443/ and add Autorize attribute with connected services. But in this case, I've got ever a 401. 
My web.config is populated with this settings

```
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="[GUID from App Id]" />
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="[tenant url]" />
<add key="ida:Audience" value="[App Id URI]" />
<add key="ida:Password" value="[hash]" />
<add key="ida:MetadataAddress" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant url]/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" />
```

On AppServices > Settings, I've updated this value

```
HomePage : https://localhost:443/
Reply Url : https://localhost:443/ (tried with https://localhost:443/.auth/login/aad/callback but same 401)
```

What am I missing ?
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: First, if you want to integrate your Native Application from your local host, you need register a **WebAPI** and then register your **Native Application** on Azure AD. But I why not just configure your app with `yourapp. azurewebsite.net`? I don't understand why you need to declare your  localhost.

Comment: I add https://localhost to reply url to authorize AAD to send me a token ? Or is it the bad way ? I try to register as native application (currently in WebApi)

Comment: I don't suggest you do like that. Just follow the steps in the document "How-to" which you post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the application registration in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com). Find your application, and then go to Settings | Reply URLs, and add the .azurewebsite.net URL